# Best way to assign view variable depending on prefix in Cake PHP 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp

In my default layout, I have a snippet that check if `$this->fetch('noindex')` is true. This allow me to don't index specific pages by adding `$this->assign('noindex', true);` in my views. But what I want, is assigning this variable to true, only when the prefix is `admin`. To this problem, I have found two solutions with one not working.

### Solution 1: In the AppController

```
public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {   
        if($this->request->param('prefix') === 'admin'){
            $this->set('noindex', true);
        }
    }
```

This way allow me to check the prefix, but I would have to do `$this->assign('noindex', $noindex);` in every views. So this is not a great solution.

### Solution 2: In the AppView (not working)

In my AppView, I can assign variables for my layouts without having to do it in all views.

```
public function initialize()
    {
        $this->assign('noindex', true);
    }
```

But I can't do it depending on the prefix.

### Solution 3: A mix (not working)

In the doc, we can see the event list of the AppView, so I though I could use the two solutions to do something working. But nothings happen.. I think that this is not the way I should use these.

```
// In AppController
public function beforeRender(Event $event)
{   
    if($this->request->param('prefix') === 'admin'){
        $this->set('noindex', true);
    }
}

// In AppView
public function afterRender()
{
    $this->assign('noindex', $noindex);
}
```

So what do you think is the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get the real problem you try to solve. I *assume* you want do to this:

```
    if ($this->request->param('prefix') === 'admin'){
        echo $this->Html->meta('robots', 'noindex, nofollow');
    }
```

Either put this directly in the layout file or create a custom helper and put it in a method of it and call it

```
echo $this->MyHelper->conditionalNoFollow();
```

in your layout(s).

And by the way, [assign](https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.View.View.html#_assign) doesn't set a variable but a blocks content. No idea if this is your intend or not.

Comment: Yes I know that this is a block but I don't put any other content in it. Your solution seems easy, I didn't know I could access request in my layout...